# SignInManager throws Invalid object name AspNetUserClaims Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.2

I am new to asp.net core. I am getting this error `"Invalid object name AspNetUserClaims"` when I try to use`signInManager` in order to log in a user. I don't want that claims part in my application, i am not storing any claims for the User.

In order to overcome this error I created `AspNetUserClaims` table but no luck, still, I am getting the same exception.

I am using asp.net core 2.2

Error Screenshot

[image]

**MUser.cs**

```
public class MUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    public ICollection<MUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**MRole.cs**

```
public class MRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
{
    public MRole() : base() {}
    public MRole(string RoleName) : base(RoleName) { }
    public ICollection<MUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

**MUserRole.cs**

```
public class MUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? TenantId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual MkTenant Tenant { get; set; }
    public virtual MUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual MRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

**CoreIdentityDbContext.cs**

```
public class CoreIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<MUser, MRole, Guid, IdentityUserClaim<Guid>, MUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<Guid>, IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>, IdentityUserToken<Guid>>
{
    public CoreIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=myDb;User=sa;password=Baskar123#", b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Mk.MId.Api"));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<MUser>().ToTable("MkUser");
        builder.Entity<MRole>().ToTable("MkRole");
        builder.Entity<MUserRole>().ToTable("MkUserRole");

        //builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<Guid>>().ToTable("MUserLogin");
        //builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<Guid>>().ToTable("MUserClaim");
        //builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<Guid>>().ToTable("MUserToken");
        //builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>>().ToTable("MRoleClaim");

        builder.Entity<MUserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            //userRole.(ur => ur.Id );

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: so you don't have have a table named AspNetUserClaims generated by EF Core? This would have been done the first migration you created.  From the looks of things you are going above and beyond and completely re-writing the Identity wheel.  While you may not be storing claims did you configure cookies or jwts?

Comment: Yes, I don't have a table named AspNetUserClaims generated by EF Core I use jwts. But my question is, Does migration is necessary? migration also going to do the same thing(I mean it will create the same table named "AspNetUserClaims" only).

Comment: Is there any Identity option to ignore AspNetUserClaims

Comment: Finally, I created the migration and updated my database. Now everything is working fine.But problem is extra tables are created.